# Header layout difficult to get in line

Tags: html, header

I am very new to HTML, I want to have a heading that has my title at the top, then below have both the logo and my name in line with each other as seen in the mock-up image below

[Image of wanted layout, background colors non specific only representational]
[image: 1]

My problem is the logo sits above the name, so even though they do not overlap each other, they do not appear in line; also, I would like for the log to be centrally aligned under the title. Currently, my code looks like this:

[What my code now looks like]    [image: 2]

My thought was to add a new div and have that alongside but still get the same problem.
Thank you for helping me, even with the most menial task.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply change `header` tag default display property which is typically block or inline to `flex`. The flex is a *

> CSS shorthand property

- It sets how a flex item will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container.

Here is an example.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #ffc000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 90px;
}

.logo h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="title">Rutherford essay</h1>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtZD224tYXnBozkVHxMu_Y0T7juacCttjX1A&usqp=CAU" alt="a dummy logo">
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <em>
           By Aman.S.Hardava
        </em>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

To further understand the use and implementation of the flex property you can refer to [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex/).